# How to access python variables from ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

In a Django web application, there is a for loop to feed a dropdown menu like below in **index.html**:

```
 <div class="form-control-lg">
        <select class="form-control " id="booklist">
            <option value="">Please select a book</option>
            {% for book in booklist %}
                 <option value="{{ book }}"> book['name']</option>
            {% endfor %}                
        </select>
 </div>
```

This code simply adds all the books in booklist to a dropdown menu.

I need to load the books from booklist but by ajax this time. I tried the below code but it does nothing, and the dropdown is empty.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 for(var book in booklist) {
                                $('#booklist').append('<option value=book>'+ book['name']  +'</option>');    
                        }    
}
```

What is the way to get the result?

Comment: Show your ajax code?

Comment: @Sumithran The ajax code is included in the question.

Comment: Nope you haven't!